# How do you skip failed migrations? (rake db:migrate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

I can't seem to find an option or anything that allows me to skip migrations.

I know what you're thinking: "you should never have to do that..."

I need to skip a migration that makes changes to specific user records that don't exist in my development database. I don't want to change the migration because it is not part of the source I am supposed to be working with. Is there a way to skip a migration or skip failed migrations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think you should fix the offending migrations to be less fragile, I'd guess that a couple of `if` statements and perhaps a `rescue` would be sufficient.

But, if fixing the migrations really isn't an option, you can fake it in various ways. First of all, you could just comment out the migration methods, run `rake db:migrate`, and then uncomment (or revert) the offending migration.

You can also fake it inside the database but this sort of chicanery is not recommended unless you know what you're doing and you don't mind manually patching things up when you (inevitably) make a mistake. There is a table in your database called `schema_migrations` that has a single `varchar(255)` column called `version`; this table is used by `db:migrate` to keep track of which migrations have been applied. All you need to do is INSERT the appropriate `version` value and `rake db:migrate` will think that the migration has been done. Find the offending migration file:

```
db/migrate/99999999999999_XXXX.rb
```

then go into your database and say:

```
insert into schema_migrations (version) values ('99999999999999');
```

where `99999999999999` is, of course, the number from the migration's file name. Then running `rake db:migrate` should skip that migration.

I'd go with the second option before the third, I'm only including the "hack `schema_versions`" option for completeness.

Comment: Ya, I just went ahead and cut out the offending migrations temporarily. I personally would have created the proper If statements or just had it check for production environment, but apparently the person who handles the migrations doesn't believe in using db:migrate while developing =P Thanks

Comment: @hmind: "the person who handles the migrations doesn't believe in using db:migrate while developing". Oh my. Publishing to your production systems must be a super happy fun time!

Comment: luckily, I don't handle that either haha

Answer (score 17):

I had an issue where I had a migration to add a table that already existed, so in my case I had to skip this migration as well, because I was getting the error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "posts" already exists: CREATE TABLE "posts"
```

I simply commented out the content of the create table method, ran the migration, and then uncommented it out. It's kind of a manual way to get around it, but it worked. See below:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # create_table :posts do |t|
    #   t.string :title
    #   t.text :message
    #   t.string :attachment
    #   t.integer :user_id
    #   t.boolean :comment
    #   t.integer :phase_id

    #   t.timestamps
    # end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16):

This is a good way to do it for one-off errors.

`db:migrate:up VERSION=my_version`

This will run one specific migration's "up" actions. (There is also the opposite if you need it, just replace "up" with "down".) So this way you can either run the future migration that makes the older one (that you need to skip) work, or just run each migration ahead of it selectively.

I also believe that you can redo migrations this way:

`rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version`

I have not tried that method personally, so YMMV.

Comment: Very nice and concise for migrate up.

Answer (score 13):

## If you have to do that, your app's migrations are messed up!

Inserts all missing migrations:

```
def insert(xxx)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("insert into schema_migrations (version) values (#{xxx})") rescue nil
end

files = Dir.glob("db/migrate/*")
files.collect { |f| f.split("/").last.split("_").first }.map { |n| insert(n) }
```

Comment: Not necessarily. For instance if you pg_restore your production database to your development machine to troubleshoot an issue with production data. Don't be so quick to tell someone they're doing it wrong when you don't have all the information.

Comment: @MikeBethany: In my case that's when I had to use it, everything was a big mess and I didn't have the time to understand why it got like that. About pg_restore, it should also restore the `schema_migrations` table I guess right?

Comment: Yeah, of course, the `schema_migrations` table is just a table in the database. Re-reading your title I can see another interpretation. I originally read it as, "You didn't write your migrations properly." What I think you actually mean is, "There is a problem with migrations." But that's obvious, hence the question, so I assumed the "you screwed up" meaning. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

To skip all pending migrations, run this in your terminal:

```
echo "a = [" $(rails db:migrate:status | grep "down" | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}' | tr '\n' ', ') "];def insert(b);ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(\"insert into schema_migrations (version) values (#{b})\") rescue nil;end;a.map { |b| insert(b)}" | xclip
```

(For macOS use pbcopy instead of xclip) 
Then CTRL-V the result inside rails console:

```
a = [ 20180927120600,20180927120700 ];def insert(b);ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("insert into schema_migrations (version) values (#{b})") rescue nil;end;a.map { |b| insert(b)}
```

And hit ENTER. 
 
You can change the list of migrations you want to skip by removing them from array **a** before executing the line.

Comment: Extremely useful in the case you have dumped a production-version of the database locally. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of skip the migration you could make your migration smart, adding some IF to it, so you can check "specific users"

Comment: Yea, that is what I would have done if I had wrote the migration. But I didn't and I don't really want to screw around with part of the source that I am not supposed to really touch so I just ended up cutting them out temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes, it is necessary to re-fill `schema_migrations` table with **definitely correct migrations**...
**ONLY FOR THIS PURPOSE** i have created this method

```
def self.insert_missing_migrations(stop_migration=nil)
  files = Dir.glob("db/migrate/*")
  timestamps = files.collect{|f| f.split("/").last.split("_").first}
  only_n_first_migrations = timestamps.split(stop_migration).first

  only_n_first_migrations.each do |version|
    sql = "insert into `schema_migrations` (`version`) values (#{version})"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) rescue nil
  end
end
```

you can copy-paste it into any model you want and use it from console

```
YourModel.insert_missing_migrations("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

*(or somehow else)*

where `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` - is timestamp of migration before which you want to stop insertion (you can leave it empty)

**!!! use it only if you absolutely understand what result will you get !!!**