# Is there a way to skip error of migration file and continue to the next file (Ruby on rails +mysql)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration

I have 424 migrations files in my app, some of them work and some not(changes made directly to the model files), I need to run all of them as part of solution to other problem,
the problem is that every time one of the files fails it's drop the whole process.

is there a way beside insert into schema_migrations the migration number(s)?

Comment: If its for development you can load schema into db with `rake db:schema:load`. It will erase current data in db so after that you need to restore db from dump

Comment: I need to make sure it's working local and then I will need to do the same of production. I can't just erase

Comment: This SO question has pretty much every single solution to skip failed migrations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810732/how-do-you-skip-failed-migrations-rake-dbmigrate

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a migration anymore you can just delete the migration file. If you are using version control you can always un-delete it in the future. But if you can skip it in production I don't know why you would ever need it again.

If deleting it is not an option it means you need it and it should be fixed. Migrations should never reference models in the `app` directory, for the exact reason you are describing. The models can change in ways that cause old migrations to fail.

If you can fix the migration to work using pure SQL, that is the best option.

If you need to use an AR model for some reason you should declare a minimal one in the migration with only what you need. That way your migration is insulated from any future model changes. Here's a simple example. In this case I would actually just use SQL, but for demonstration:

```rb
class UpdateUserDisplayNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Any reference to User in the scope of this migration will
  # reference this class, insulating the migration from changes
  # to the User class in app/models
  class User < ApplicationRecord; end;

  def up
    User.find_each do |u|
      u.update!(display_name: "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}"
    end
  end
end
```